# Probability of Energy Levels in an Infinite Potential Well

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy-conservation

There's a problem in Shankar's QM text where it asks you to find the probability that a wave function in an infinite potential well is in the ground state if the potnetial barriers where suddenly moved symmetrically $V(0): [-L/2, L/2] \rightarrow [-L,L]$. This got me thinking about what would happen if the potential walls were kept at their original positions. What doesn't seem to make sense is that no matter which eigenfunctions I test, I always get the answer $1$.

$$ P(n) =\langle \psi _2 \rvert \psi _n \rangle ^2 = \left[ \frac{2}{L}\int ^{L/2} _{-L/2} \sin^2 \left(\frac{2  \pi x}{L}\right)dx \right]^2 =1$$
The problem seems to be that the eigenfunctions are all normalized, since the only thing that changes between them is the integer $n$ inside the sine or cosine function, they're value under an integral is the same. How does this make physical sense?

My second question is *why* there should even be a probability (for energy) in a square well. It seems impossible to set up such a system without already knowing what energy level the particle would be in. If the energy level of the function was really random, wouldn't that violate energy conservation? I'm not sure I'm doing a good job wording my question, but hopefully you understand what I'm getting at. When we move the potential barriers of the well, if the particle is in a state $\lvert \psi _1 \rangle$, it has a well defined energy and moving the barrier shouldn't somehow create energy.

Comment: Yes, the eigenfunctions you use are all normalised. Your formula for $P(n)$ is the probability of finding the particle in the well *when* it is at quantum state $n$. That is of course always $1$. No surprise there. So what really is your question?

Comment: Hm, I thought that $\lvert \psi _n \rangle$ was the state vector in the energy eigenbasis, meaning each of the $n$ kets were its projection along that particular energy level. Is that not true? If it is, it would follow that $\langle \psi _{n'} \lvert \psi _n \rangle ^2$ would be the probability of finding it in a state $\lvert \psi _{n'}\rangle$.

Comment: The third part of your equation is simply $\psi_n^2$, integrated over the domain of the particle. If $\psi$ is normalised, then *by definition* that integral equals $1$.

Comment: If we pretend that $\lvert \psi \rangle$ is two dimensional dimensional, don't we have $\lvert \psi \rangle = c_1 \lvert \psi _1 \rangle + c_2 \lvert \psi _2 \rangle$ and then $\langle \psi _2 \lvert \psi \rangle ^2 = c_2 ^2$. That's correct, right? If it's correct, it would mean for our case that there is zero probability the state vector is in any other state. I don't know what I'm not seeing here.

Comment: @Qmechanic: help us out here, please?

Comment: This notation looks confused. The state vector is some vector $|\phi \rangle$. There is no such thing as a state vector "in the energy eigenbasis" (it's just the state vector!) but you can find the coefficients of the state vector in the energy eigenbasis $|\psi_i \rangle$.

Comment: I think you're saying that state $|\phi \rangle$ is equal to $|\psi_2 \rangle$. In this case, $\langle \phi | \psi_2 \rangle = 1$, i.e. the state is definitely $| \psi_2 \rangle$, and $\langle \phi | \psi_i \rangle = 0$ for any other $i$. You're just saying the state vector has a 100% chance of being itself.

Comment: @kevinZhou look at this answer http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/146017/probability-of-energy-from-wavefunction in our case, what should is our $\psi (x)$?

Comment: I don't get what you mean. Does this disagree with my comment?

Comment: No, I don't think it does. I just think all of my confusion is coming from not understanding what the "state vector" actually is. It would fix all of my problems if somebody could *show* how to find the probability of a particular energy state. It should be that $\langle n = 1 \lvert \Psi \rangle ^2$ is the probability for of the particle being in the ground state, but what actually is $\lvert \Psi \rangle$ in this case?

Comment: Please post an exact wording of Shankar's question or a reference. The problem and your question are unclear.

Comment: @Astrum, I totally get your confusion! The state vector is a bit abstract.

Comment: Here's a very simple example: consider the polarization of a photon going along the $z$ axis. The state vector $|\psi \rangle$ is the actual direction the polarization is pointing. You can expand it in components as $|\psi \rangle = c_1 |x \rangle + c_2 |y \rangle$. Then $c_1^2 = |\langle \psi | x \rangle|^2$ is the probability the polarization is measured to be horizontal. However, $|\psi \rangle$ itself has nothing to do with the horizontal/vertical basis, or the components $c_1$ or $c_2$. It's a direction. It exists independently of any particular basis choice.

Comment: In your problem, the state is still a vector, just in a more abstract space. There's no physical interpretation of the "way it points". However, you can still expand it in components, either in the energy basis $|n \rangle$ or the position basis $|x \rangle$, etc.

Comment: Maybe the most confusing part is, hey, if the state vector is independent of any basis, how do you say what it _is_? Usually, you just say what its components in a basis are. For example, "it starts in the ground state" means $|\psi \rangle = |n=1\rangle$, or alternatively $\langle \psi | n=1\rangle^2 = 1$ and hence $\langle \psi | n=2\rangle^2 = 1$, etc. Or, "the wavefunction is $f(x)$" means $\langle x | \psi \rangle = f(x)$.